# Prove: $a_{n}$ is Cauchy sequence

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Prove: the squance $a_n=(\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{1}{2^n})$ is a Cauchy sequence

The proof starts with:

$$||a_{n}-a_{m}||=\sqrt{2}(\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^m})$$

Where did we get $\sqrt{2}$ from?

I know that

$$||a_{n}-a_{m}||=||(\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{1}{2^n})-(\frac{1}{2^m},\frac{1}{2^m})||=||(\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^m},\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^m})||=\sqrt{(\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^m})^2+(\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^m})^2}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{4^{n}}+\frac{2}{{4^m}}-\frac{4}{2^{n+m}}}$$

Comment: $$\sqrt{\Big(\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^m}\Big)^2+\Big(\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^m}\Big)^2}=\sqrt{2\Big(\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^m}\Big)^2}=\sqrt{2}\Big|\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^m}\Big|.$$

Comment: What does $\{\frac1{2^n},\frac1{2^n}\}$ even mean?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Sorry, edited

Comment: @gbox: $\sqrt{2}$ comes from the Pythagorean theorem in the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said,
\begin{align*}
||a_{n}-a_{m}||=||(\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{1}{2^n})-(\frac{1}{2^m},\frac{1}{2^m})||=||(\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^m},\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^m})||=\sqrt{(\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^m})^2+(\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^m})^2}=
\sqrt{2(\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^m})^2}=\sqrt{2}\left|\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^m}\right|.
\end{align*}